# Passing name inside the toolbar

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help me on how to parse name of user's every time they logged in inside a toolbar?thank you :). I've been searching for tutorials about that but I can't find even one.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, you want to set title or subtitle. You can do that with this code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Username");
getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Username2");
```

Also please take a look at [ActionBar developer doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the title of toolbar by this code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```